# Changing the format string for numeric floating point values in the Put function

Tags: output-formatting

In my current macro, I have:

```
Put[Chop[someList], "someFile"];
```

where "someList" is a mixed bag of "strings", "integers", "exact complex values" (e.g. `(-1)^(1/3)`) and "numeric floating point complex values".
The `Chop` function nicely cleans all numeric elements which are close to zero.
I am now looking for a way to specify the format string for non-zero "numeric floating point values", which would output at most some number of "significant" decimal digits (e.g. 7, instead of the default 17).

An example of my "someList":

```
someList = {{{"a string"}, {1, 2}}, {{3, 4}, {Exp[I/3], (-1)^(2/3)}}, {{5, 6}, {1.23456789 + 9.87654321*I, -9.87654321 + 1.23456789*I}}};
```

for which, I would like to get (assuming 6 "significant digits"):

```
{{{"a string"}, {1, 2}}, {{3, 4}, {E^(I/3), (-1)^(2/3)}}, {{5, 6}, {1.23457 + 9.87654*I, -9.87654 + 1.23457*I}}}
```

**Update (2019.08.14)**: It seems that, despite repeated requests that can be found in the Internet, Mathematica does not provide any C-like "printf" (low level) formatted output conversion functionality.
For the time being, I (mostly) solved my problem by using this trick:

```
InexactToExact[x_Real] := 
  Which[PossibleZeroQ[Chop[FullSimplify[x]]], 0, 
        PossibleZeroQ[Chop[FullSimplify[x - 1]]],  1, 
        PossibleZeroQ[Chop[FullSimplify[x + 1]]], -1, 
        PossibleZeroQ[Chop[FullSimplify[x - 3]]],  3, 
        PossibleZeroQ[Chop[FullSimplify[x + 3]]], -3, 
        PossibleZeroQ[Chop[FullSimplify[x - 1/3]]],  1/3, 
        PossibleZeroQ[Chop[FullSimplify[x + 1/3]]], -1/3, 
        PossibleZeroQ[Chop[FullSimplify[x - Sqrt[3]]]],  Sqrt[3], 
        PossibleZeroQ[Chop[FullSimplify[x + Sqrt[3]]]], -Sqrt[3], 
        PossibleZeroQ[Chop[FullSimplify[x - Sqrt[3]/3]]],  Sqrt[3]/3, 
        PossibleZeroQ[Chop[FullSimplify[x + Sqrt[3]/3]]], -Sqrt[3]/3, 
        (* and so on for any "special" real value that you need *) 
        True, x] (* all another real values *)
InexactToExact[z_Complex] := 
  Which[PossibleZeroQ[Chop[FullSimplify[z]]], 0, 
        PossibleZeroQ[Chop[FullSimplify[z - (-1)^(1/3)]]],  (-1)^(1/3), 
        PossibleZeroQ[Chop[FullSimplify[z + (-1)^(1/3)]]], -(-1)^(1/3), 
        PossibleZeroQ[Chop[FullSimplify[z - (-1)^(1/3)*Sqrt[3]]]],  (-1)^(1/3)*Sqrt[3], 
        PossibleZeroQ[Chop[FullSimplify[z + (-1)^(1/3)*Sqrt[3]]]], -(-1)^(1/3)*Sqrt[3], 
        PossibleZeroQ[Chop[FullSimplify[z - (-1)^(1/3)/Sqrt[3]]]],  (-1)^(1/3)/Sqrt[3], 
        PossibleZeroQ[Chop[FullSimplify[z + (-1)^(1/3)/Sqrt[3]]]], -(-1)^(1/3)/Sqrt[3], 
        (* and so on for any "special" complex value that you need *) 
        InexactNumberQ[z], FullSimplify[(InexactToExact[Re[z]]) + (InexactToExact[Im[z]]) * I], 
        True, z] (* all another complex values *)
InexactToExact[v:Except[_Real | _Complex]] := v (* all another types of values *)

someList = Replace[Chop[FullSimplify[someList]], {v_:>InexactToExact[v]}, {-1}];
Put[someList, "someFile"];
```

Unfortunately, the above trick does not work for many "exact" values. It seems to me that the problem is that Mathematica returns "Complex" for `Head[3+I]` and `Head[3*I]` but it happily returns "Plus" and "Times" for, respectively, `Head[Sqrt[3]+I]` and `Head[Sqrt[3]*I]`.

Comment: `NumberForm[#,{\[Infinity],7}]` or the same with `DecimalForm`, which gives only decimal form without scientific notation.

Comment: Thanks. I tried `Put[NumberForm[Chop[someList], {\[Infinity],7}], "someFile"];` but, in the file, it simply saves "NumberForm\[originalText, {\\[Infinity\],7}\]".

Comment: Yu may use `Export` function: `Export["somefile",Map[NumberForm[Chop[#], {\[Infinity], 7}] &,Table[{x, x^2, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, \[Pi], 0.1}],{2}],"Table"]`. I used generated table here to show exporting to file with 3 columns of numbers of desired form.

Comment: Thanks again. It still doesn't work, sorry (I added an example of my "someList" above and, as one can see, I would need a solution which automatically deals with nested lists of different kinds of elements). Another problem with `NumberForm` is that it always outputs all "requested" digits, including the trailing zeros (e.g. one gets `0.0000000` instead of simply `0.`).

Comment: I think I would need a way to modify the "format string" for the lowest level routine which writes numeric floating point values in the `InputForm` (used by the `Put` function).

Comment: Maybe this is what you need: `ClearAll[f]; f[x_Real] := NumberForm[Chop[x], {\[Infinity], 7}]; f[x_Complex /; FractionalPart /@ ReIm[x] != {0, 0}] := NumberForm[Chop[x], {\[Infinity], 7}]; f[x_] := x`. So, I defined a function which works only with Real numbers (with decimal point) and Complex numbers with "decimals" in there. Other parts are not affected.

Comment: Many thanks again. I've just realized that I cannot use `NumberForm` (nor `ScientificForm`). Everything must be written in the `InputForm` as the output file (generated by `Put`) will later be given to the `Get` function (in another macro).

Answer (score 1):

**Updated to handle numbers in scientific notation**

You could block the formatting of [`Real`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Real) objects:

```
Block[{Real},
    Format[r_Real, InputForm] := StandardForm @ NumberForm[
        r,
        3,
        NumberFormat -> (Replace[#3, {"" -> #1, _ -> StringJoin[#1, "*^", #3]}]&)
    ];
    Put[someList, "tstfile.txt"]
]
```

Check:

```
Import["tstfile.txt"]
```

> "{{{\"a string\"}, {1, 2}}, {{3, 4}, {E^(I/3), (-1)^(2/3)}}, {{5, 6}, {1.23 + 9.88*I, -9.88 + 1.23*I}}}"

Comment: @WileE. See update.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to go one step further and convert "inexact" numbers into "exact" ones (see my "update" above). Fortunately, I only need to deal with several tens of various "magic" values.